# Text fields with different alignment inside one button

Tags: go, fyne

Is it possible to extend Fyne’s widget button to accept two different text fields with different alignment inside one button?
For example, I want a button to contain:

|FILE_NAME  ....... FILE_SIZE|

I tried to add additional Text field to my structure of a button, but it was ignored.

**Update**

This is how I tried to add second text

```
func NewBasicIconButton (text, secondText string, icon fyne.Resource, action func()) *BasicButton {
b := &BasicButton{
    widget.Button{
        Text: text,
        Alignment: widget.ButtonAlignLeading,
        Icon: icon,
        IconPlacement: widget.ButtonIconLeadingText,
        OnTapped: action,
    },
    secondText,
    widget.ButtonAlignTrailing,

}

b.ExtendBaseWidget(b)
return b
```

}

Comment: Please provide a code example so we can help.

Answer (score 0):

The Fyne `widget.Button` doesn't really do that - it provides for 1 text and 1 icon, although they can be aligned separately the icon cannot be string content.
You probably need a custom widget to do that.

Comment: So it's not extending of existing button widget, but creating a new one?